# Calculation of per unit of Electricity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a electrical units calculator. I have developed one but I am not satisfied with my code. I am here to ask you guys is there any other way to develop this calculator.

Following is my code :

**HTML**

```
<input name="" type="text" value="" onblur="check()" id="bill" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    function check()
    {
    var a=0,b=0,c=0;
    var tot = 0;
    var tot1=0;
    var tot2=0;
    var tot3=0;

    var a = document.getElementById('bill').value;

    if(a>200)
    {
        b = a - 200;
        alert('b is: '+b);
        if(b>200)
        {
        c= b-200;
        alert('c is: '+c);
        tot1 = 200*4;
        tot2 = 200*5;
        tot3 = c*6;
        tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3;
        alert(tot);
        }
        else
        {

        tot1 = 200*4;
        tot2 = b*5;
        tot3 = c*6;
        tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3;
        alert(tot);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        tot = a*4;
        alert(tot);

    }
    }

</script>
```

Please help me friends..:)

Comment: What aren't you satisfied with?

Comment: i just want to narrow my code

Comment: magic numbers everywhere, variable names as clear as if they were pre-obfuscated... I have no idea what this function does :/

Comment: What is the algorithm like?

Comment: Very hard to advise without knowing what the function is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
     function check()
    {
    var a=0,b=0,c=0;
    var tot = 0;
    var tot1=0;
    var tot2=0;
    var tot3=0;

    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bill').value);

    if(a>200)
    {
        tot1 = 200*4;
        b = a - 200;
        alert('b is: '+b);
        if(b>200)
        {
        c= b-200;
        alert('c is: '+c);
        tot2 = 200*5;
        tot3 = c*6;
        tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3;
        alert(tot);
        }
        else
        {

        tot1 = 200*4;
        tot2 = b*5;
        tot3 = c*6;
        tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3;
        alert(tot);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        tot = a*4;
        alert(tot);

    }
    }
</script>
<input name="" type="text" value="" onblur="check()" id="bill" />
```

I think this will do :)

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: The statement

tot1 = 200*4;

was not taking place for range 201 to 400 :) it was nested in third condition :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to be separated - as well comments are useful to help others understand the purpose of your code.  Here's a working example of one:

```
function check() 
{   var initialRate = 4; // electricity charged at this rate below 200
    var standardRate = 5; // amount of electricity between 200 and 400 charged at this rate
    var overageRate = 6; // the part of electricity usage over 400 at this rate
    var electricityUsage = +document.getElementById('bill').value; // convert String to Number

    if (isFinite(electricityUsage) || electricityUsage < 0) {
        alert('The number entered was invalid, or was less than 0.');
        return;
    }

    // calculates the total
    alert(
        electricityUsage > 400
        ? initialRate * 200 + standardRate * 200 + overageRate * (electricityUsage - 400)
        : electricityUsage > 200
            ? initialRate * 200 + standardRate * (electricityUsage - 200)
            : initialRate * electricityUsage
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function check()
{
    // Algorithm
    // Slabs : 200 | 400 | ...
    // Amoun :  4  |  5  |  6

    slabs = [200, 400]
    rate = [4, 5, 6]

    var total = document.getElementById('bill').value;

    // Over the head
    if (total > slabs[1]) {
        amount = slabs[0] * rate[0] + (slabs[1] - slabs[0]) * rate[1] + (total - slabs[1]) * rate[2];
    } else if (total > slabs[0]) {
        amount = slabs[0] * rate[0] + (total - slabs[0]) * rate[1];
    } else {
        amount = total * rate[0];
    }

    alert("Total charge: " + amount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it at last. There are three charge-bands and you need to know what portion of a value is in each band. Then you need to apply appropriate multipliers to the amount in each band.

If I'm right, then the code is painfully simple :

```
function check() {
    var a = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
    var n = 200;
    var tot1 = Math.min(n, a);
    a = a - n;
    var tot2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, a));
    a = a - n;
    var tot3 = Math.max(0, a);
    return tot1 * 4 + tot2 * 5 + tot3 * 6;
}
```

If there were more bands then we would do the calcs in a loop but for three bands this is adequate.

Note: The function returns the calculated total.

Comment: Wow, much cleaner than my example.  I like how you made use of the various Math functions, makes it easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

See this: **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vTsUC/)**

```
function check()
{
    var tot = 0,tot1=0,tot2=0,tot3=0;
    var a = document.getElementById('bill').value;
    tot1 = (a<=200) ? (a * 4) : 800;
    tot2 = (a<=400) ? ((a-200) * 5): 1000;
    tot3 = (a-400) > 0 ? ((a-400) * 6): 0;
    tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3;
    var msg = "Total Charge: "+tot+"\n Details\n < 200        : "+tot1;
        msg += (tot2 != 0) ? "\n200 to 400 : "+tot2 : "";
        msg += (tot3 != 0) ? "\n>400          : "+ tot3 : "";
    alert(msg);
}
```